# breaking into IPython notebook server at arbitrary line?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I usually do the following trick for debugging, add following snippet to a place where I want to break into IPython shell:

```
from IPython.terminal import embed
ipshell = embed.InteractiveShellEmbed()
ipshell()
```

Does anyone know of a way to do something similar, but instead of spawning shell, start an interactive notebook session in browser?

Answer (score 0):

For that to work, you'd have to either

- have the thing you're trying to debug already running in your python notebook daemon's control,
- or you'd have to have a debugging backend that you can attach to your  process started from within your notebook daemon.

Since the second, to my knowledge, doesn't exist (yet), your only option would be to start the program you want to debug from within your notebook.

Comment: Option 1 is doable, but how do stop evaluation and cede the control to the notebook?